# XCTest after test case?

Tags: xctest

I am writing integration tests with a docket printer and I need it to cut the docket after all the unit tests in a single suite are complete.

Other test frameworks I've used have a `tearDownAfterClass` type action, but XCTest doesn't seem to have that?

Is there anyway I can simulate this?

Answer (score 3):

> Other test frameworks I've used have a tearDownAfterClass type action, but XCTest doesn't seem to have that?

`XCTest` has exactly that feature. There are two versions of `tearDown`, one an instance method and one a class method:

```
- (void)tearDown;    // this gets called after each test
+ (void)tearDown;    // this gets called after all tests in the suite
```

Similarly, there are instance and class versions of `setUp`, so you can do setup work before each test or once before the suite runs.

Answer (score 0):

There is a crude solution to this. It turns out that XCTest always runs tests in alphabetical order, so like:

```
/**
 * Tests are run in alphabetical order, hence the Z so this runs last.
 */
- (void)testZTearDownAfterClass
{
   // ...
}
```

The same would conversely be true about `setUpBeforeClass`:

```
- (void)test_setUpBeforeClass
{
   // ...
}
```

Comment: There's no need for this -- like OCUnit, XCTestCase has methods for setup and teardown.